# Java generic erasing after Java 8

Tags: java, generics

I know that Java generic type information is erased at runtime. I have sort-of-abused this to put "wrongly typed" objects into maps to mark mapping to `null`s:

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{
    private static final Object NULL = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Map<String, String> kek = new HashMap<>();
        kek.put("foo", maskNull(null));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
    public static <T> T maskNull(T value)
    {
        return value != null ? value : (T) NULL;
    }
}
```

Of course in real code I would use sth. like `maskNull(foo)` where `foo` could be anything, so I wouldn't know if it was `null` or not in advance. Functions like `isMaskedNull()` etc. are omitted for brevity.

This used to work fine in Java 8. However, now that I'm trying to upgrade to Java 11, I get the following error at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Object and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at test.main(test.java:10)
```

As I understand, Java compiler now implicitly emits type-casting operation before `put()` is called. Is there a way out of it, i.e. can I get the old behavior at least in specifically marked (I don't know, with an annotation?) cases?

Comment: You deliberately used [heap pollution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_pollution) with your null object trick. Find another solution, because heap pollution is bad and you certainly don't want to use it like this.

Comment: Interesting! I cannot reproduce this working on Java 8, though, using `1.8.0_292` I get a the expected `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String`.

Comment: @PetrJaneček: Might depend on what you do with it. Of course I would always check if it is a "masked null" first using omitted `isMaskedNull()` function: otherwise you get an implicit cast to `String` on *getting*. But e.g. `System.out.println(kek.get("foo")==NULL);` works here (1.8.0_212).

Comment: What's the reason for you not "just" storing the null? Granted, you cannot then use `map.get(key) != null`, but you can still use `map.containsKey(key)` and the newer `map.getOrDefault(key, "EMPTY_VALUE")`.

Comment: @Jesper: "is bad", "you don't want". I have used this trick for years in performance-critical code and it worked fine. It's conceptually the same as using a `Map<String, Object>`, then casting said `Object` to `String` if it is not `NULL`. Of course, this is only used in internal maps private to one class and only in performance-critical places. Otherwise when `get()` returns a `null` this may be because the value is really `null` or because there is no such key in the map, and sometimes it is important to distinguish those cases.

Comment: I got the `ClassCastException` on the `.put` call, on your exact code. So probably this was a bug and got fixed between 1.8u212 and 1.8u292. Or it's a "regression", but more likely "this was unspecified and we improved it". That said, I went through the Java 8 release notes and did not find any mention of this there. Try bisecting the version that "broke" this to pinpoint the change.

Comment: @PetrJaneček: Thank you for investigation. If this is not even mentioned in release notes, then there is no hope they added something to switch it off. I'll have to rewrite the code then.

Comment: Yeah. I'd personally go with the option of storing the nulls, and then using `containsKey()` and/or `getOrDefault()` upon retrieval. You could also change your map to `<String, Object>`, or use a very unique String as a null object and hope it will never come up as an actual value. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

At least as on Java 11.0.15, you can still force your `NULL` value into the map if you pull the same trick you did in `maskNull()` to bypass the checking around `put()`. However, you'll just get an error somewhere else. The point is: **Java will assume that you have not stored the wrong type of object, but will sometimes check this assumption. You can't assume once you "get away with it" once it won't be checked later; and you can't easily predict from one version of `javac` to another when it might be checked.** So you should find a different way of achieving your perfomance (and as always with performance, test, don't guess.)

But yes, if you define:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <K, V> void badPut(Map<K, V> m, K key, V value) {
  m.put(key, maskNull(value));
}
```

Then this "works":

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
badPut(m, "test", null);
System.out.println(m.get("test") == NULL);
```

as does this:

```
Object o = m.get("test");
System.out.println(o);
```

However, this **doesn't** work, it compiles but throws a `ClassCastException` at runtime:

```
String value = m.get("test");
if (value == NULL) { ... }
```

And it errors on the first line: you can't `get()` your `NULL` into a `String`. Each of these also throw the exception:

```
System.out.println(m.get("test"));

String masked = maskNull(null);
```

So it seems to me you can't have your cake and eat it, too: you can't treat your values as `String`s *and* have some of them not be strings, unless you treat the map like a `Map<String, Object>` and then cast the value to `String`. Of course, you could just declare your map that way to begin with and avoid these unpredictable exceptions.

It's a shame there isn't a public method like `Map.Entry<K, V> getEntry(key)` on `HashMap`, as there is a package-private one, `getNode`, that appears to me to not create any new objects. That would give you what you want, a way to do one key lookup, and then test for existence and value without triggering another lookup. Maybe you could copy the source for `HashMap` into your project and add the public method yourself. Or you could look into [Apache Commons collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/), which appear to have their `getEntry` method `protected`, which means you could subclass and use it. (However, they mention `getEntry` as *not* being the most efficient way to access the map.)

And as Petr Janeček said, if these are `String` values, you could solve this pretty easily with `getOrDefault`:

```
static final String MISSING = "<something you are certain won't clash>"

String value = map.getOrDefault(key, MISSING);
if (value == MISSING) {
  ...
} else if (value == null) {
  ...
} else {
  // use value
}
```